# How to fix Latte Dock Setup?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 19.04, plasma, dock

I am trying to setup the Latte Dock as a widget attached to the bottom panel (in order to allow it to be visible over full screen applications) and even though I have the settings set to be centered, the dock seems to stick to the right and cut off at the end of the panel and I can't fix it. I would like the final outcome to make the panel behave like the Mac doc. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to run it from application menu. You added it as widget, but you have to run as an application. Then it will appear in the bottom centre